# How can I measure hardware specs for Continuous Integration server (Jenkins)?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

Jenkins' webpage does speak about server specifications. The matter is that I have to ask to systems a server for CI, and I have to specify those requirements, and of course justify them.

I have to decide the following things:

- Hard disk capacity, for the whole server, considering the OS. This spec is considered the more critical for the hardware providers.
- RAM.
- Number of cores.

And these are the things to take into account:

- The OS they'll provide me will probably be Ubuntu Server.
- I'm not going to run more than 1 build simultaneously, in the 99'9% of the cases.
- I'm going to work with Moodle, so the source code size will be quite much (the whole repo is of about 700Mb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding my experience with Jenkins and Linux, I would recommend the following configuration:

- A CentOS machine or VM (Ubuntu Server is OK too)
- Minimum 2 CPU
- Minimum 2 GB of RAM
- A 30 GB partition for the OS
- Another partition for Jenkins (like /jenkins)

Regarding the partition size for Jenkins, it depends of the number of jobs (and their workspaces size).

My Jenkins partition is 100 GB (I have around 100 jobs and some large Git repo to clone).

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience, it's very useful for me to make an approximate measurement.
I think 100 GB for Jenkins will be so much; I think the best for measuring this will be to install an instance with Jenkins and try it, and see how much space takes for my projects.

Comment: Yep it's a good idea to proceed like that. Good luck for your configuration :)

Comment: Looks good.  Please check https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Best+Practices.  It is better to have "slaves" on separate environment.  We run masters on VMs on a virtual environment.